# Is there a way to add an extra value (not in db model) to an existent model and return its?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 models - Book (title), Author (name) and Written (author_id,book_id).

My foreign-key works perfectly.

I want, for a strange case, when GETS all books with the http_get call, the list of other books written by same author. I explain with an example:

```
BOOK = <1: "LOTR - The Fellowship of the Ring"> ; <2: "LOTR - The Two Towers> ; <3: "HARRY POTTER - The Philosopher's Stone> ; <4: "LOTR - The Return of the king"> ; <5: "HARRY POTTER - The Chamber of Secrets">.

AUTHOR = <1: "Tolkien"> ; <2: "Rowling">.

WRITTEN = <1: 1,1> ; <2: 1,2> ; <3: 1,4> ; <4: 2,3> ; <5: 2,5>
```

Fine! When I do my GET_REQUEST for all books, I want obtain :

```
{
"id":"1",
"title":"LOTR-The Fellowship of the Ring",
"author-id":"1",
"other-books":"[2,4]"
},

{
"id":"2",
"title":"LOTR-The Two Towers",
"author-id":"1",
"other-books":"[1,4]"
},
```

and so on..

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? This question is confusing to me.

Comment: You will need to query books and include the author and written associated. then you will need to loop to structure your output the way you want above or using your serializer...hope this gives you some hints.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you are trying to do is setup a many to many assocation beween books and authors and then create a nested route. Which is actually a pretty mundane thing.

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :authorships
  has_many :authors, through: :authorships
end

class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :authorships
  has_many :authors, through: :authorships
end

# "Written" is a lousy name for a model since its not a noun
class Authorship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :author
end
```

Using m-2-m is a pretty solid choice since it lets you handle multiple authors.

You can then setup a nested route:

```
resources :authors do
  resources :books, module: :authors, only: [:index]
end
```

And a controller that will respond to `/authors/:author_id/books`.

```
module Authors
  class BooksController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_author

    # GET /authors/1/books
    # GET /authors/1/books.json
    def index
      @books = @author.books
      render json: @books
    end

    private
    def set_author
       @author = Author.includes(:books)
                       .find(params[:author_id])
    end
  end
end
```

The reason I'm using `module: :authors` is that it lets you create seperate controllers for the nested and unnested representations of the resource (`/books`) without a bunch of code branches in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

**As per my understanding,**

You have 3 models - Book (title), Author (name) and Written (author_id,book_id).

When you do 
book = Book.first

author = book.author (as book belongs to author)

***`

> other_books = author.books.map(&:id) - book.id

`***

(You can get other books by getting all book ids of that particular author, and then subtracting the particular book id from that.